# (R.layout.splash); splash cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse, xcode, splash-screen

I'm in the middle of making my first Android app on eclipse, and I am running into a problem. Basically I'm getting a splash cannot be resolved or is not a field error. 
The code was working 10 min ago. The following link is to this project in my dropbox. That away if you want, you can test some theories out on it. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1sg8p9uvjbolqxx/AADcMiPWB_JVEysb01B_hUtBa
The following is a copy of the code the Java side.

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.techreviewsandhelp.carteretcountyhistoryguide.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#000000" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/splash"> 
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/trh" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: BTW I did add the splash ID to the xml. Here is the code from there.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/splash">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/trh" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: try cleaning your project

Comment: probably you have messed up your xml file. Are there any errors in xml file? And if there is `import android.R` then delete it.

Comment: if you are showing some images in splash screen make sure u comply to android standard , that is image name  should not contain numbers and capitals letters, if it contains such things that can corrupt your R file,just check

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you dont have erros in the layout splash file. Probably the project is not building the R because you have an error in some XML file. Try to find it and clear the project.

Comment: I don't have any errors anywhere else. In fact, I don't even have any warnings on the splash.xml.

Comment: I just added a dropbox link in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to replace this code:

import android.os.Handler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.splash);

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(Splash.this,MAINACTIVITY.class);
         startActivity(openStartingPoint);
      }
   },5000);
}
```

Comment: That added 12 errors. The splash error is still there, and now it has the following.
MAINACTIVITY cannot be resolved to a type
Handler cannot be resolved to a type
Syntax error line 34

Then the rest of the areas are syntax errors on what was already there.

Comment: I just added a dropbox link in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to you guys. When I was undoing the code you had me put in, I found out the following was messing up the layout read.
import android.R;

Thanks for everyones help.